# Add a jquery effect to this dropdown code

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown code that works fine, it does a simple display. But, I'd like to add a simple jQuery effect like slideDown. How would I add that in?

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
{  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
   closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

Thanks.

Comment: We would expect you to try something first

Comment: I did try out a few things, nothing worked. I'm not very much of a coder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your jsddm_open and jsddm_close function with the following:
For [speed] you can either use  "slow", "fast", "normal", or a number of milliseconds for the effect.

```
function jsddm_open()
{
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').show([speed],[callback]);
}

function jsddm_close()
{
    if(ddmenuitem)
        ddmenuitem.hide([speed]);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work? Could you paste the full code?

Comment: I can't add the full code as a comment, sorry. But simple replace the line 5 to 11 in your skript and insert the following example:
    function jsddm_open()
    {
        jsddm_canceltimer();
        jsddm_close();
        ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').show("normal");
    }
    
    function jsddm_close()
    {
        if(ddmenuitem)
            ddmenuitem.hide("normal");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').slideDown();}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.slideUp();}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
{  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
   closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

Comment: It does slide down and up, but it does it in a loop endlessly while hovering, instead of once on mouseover and once on mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing this row:

```
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

with something like this:

```
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').fadeIn('slow');
```

as well as this row:

```
if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

with something like this:

```
if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.fadeOut('slow');
```

The fadeIn and the fadeOut can be changed to any effect, that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these two functions:

```
function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').slideDown();}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.slideUp();}
```